# find tree for undirected unweighted rooted graph

Tags: graph, tree, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am beginner on the field of steiner tree problem and i need to identify the name of my problem and if that's exist:
Given undirected, unweighted, rooted graph and some vertice (temrinal nodes). I want to construct tree where all terminal node are leafs with minimal number of steiner vertices.
Can any one identify for me the class( name) of this problem for read more about this.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the terminal Steiner tree problem eg. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019002002272). A more common Name seems to be full Steiner tree eg. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397503002093).

There is also research on unweighted full Steiner tree which is closer to what you are looking for.

As you are considering an unweighted graph, reducing the number of vertices of the tree is equivalent to reducing the number edges, as |V(T)| = |E(T)|+1 for every tree T.

To make sure the root node r is included in the tree you can add an extra node r' with an edge {r,r'} to your graph and make r' a terminal.

Comment: Steiner's terminal tree problem considers that each terminal node must be a leaf close to my problem. but in my problem we can consider all edges have the same weight and the undirected graph with a root vertex r. The objective is to find tree with root r and minimal number of steiner vertex. am i still in the context of steiner tree problem? does it have any work on the same model? I did not find me

Comment: As you are undirected you want the root to be just any of the nodes in the Steiner tree?

Comment: The root node is predefined node in the graph

Comment: But what role shall the root node have in the Steiner tree?

Comment: is the only node that has at least one path to each terminal node

Comment: I think you are correct, my problem is similar to the unweighted full steiner tree, we just add the root node. So what can we say about this difference?

Comment: As you are in an undirected graph every node should have a path to every other node. At least when you are connected. And Steiner trees cant be found if not all terminals are in the same connected component.

So if the root note is the only node that is allowed to be not a leaf in the Steiner tree I have adjusted my answer to make your problem a special case of undirected full Steiner tree.

Comment: how i can prouve that my problem is a special case of undirected full Steiner tree?      
do you have any paper about that ?  thank you sir

Comment: Id indeed the root node is the only terminal that is allowed more than 1 neighbour in the Steiner Tree (i.e. not a leaf) then I have provided the idea of the proof in my answer. You add an extra node that you only connect to your root node with one edge. Then you take all the original terminals together with the new node as the terminals for the unweighted full Steiner tree problem.

Comment: I didn't understand your idea

Comment: At what point are you struggling? Do you see that your problem is undirected full Steiner tree with the exception the special root node? When I understand you correctly this root node has to be contained in you Steiner tree but is allowed to have more than one edge (not a node) while all other terminals have to be leaves? Is everything up to that point correct and clear?

Comment: So the only thing which is unclear is the construction of adding the extra node?

Comment: yes if you mean the root node by the extra node. So we have one root, set of terminal nodes and set of  steiner nodes the objective is to find steiner tree which minimze the number of steiner vertice and connect all terminal node with the root node that's my problem. i thnik is similaire to node weigthed steiner tree where all steiner vertice have the same weigth and the graph is undirected with one root node. what do you thinks ?